# Redux actions without return or dispatch

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am implementing Oauth from google with redux, and I wanted to have all google API calls handled from my redux and ended up writing helper functions in my actions file that doesn't return anything or call dispatch. I ended up with code where I only dispatch once from my JSX file and wondering if this is okay or there is another better way to do it?

The code is as follows: 
authActions.js

```
const clientId = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_OAUTH_KEY;
let auth;

export const authInit = () => (dispatch) => {
  window.gapi.load('client:auth2', () =>
    window.gapi.client.init({ clientId, scope: 'email' }).then(() => {
      auth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      dispatch(changeSignedIn(auth.isSignedIn.get()));
      auth.isSignedIn.listen((signedIn) => dispatch(changeSignedIn(signedIn)));
    })
  );
};

export const signIn = () => {
  auth.signIn();
};

export const signOut = () => {
  auth.signOut();
};

export const changeSignedIn = (signedIn) => {
  const userId = signedIn ? auth.currentUser.get().getId() : null;

  return {
    type: SIGN_CHANGE,
    payload: { signedIn, userId },
  };
};
```

GoogleAuth.jsx

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { authInit, signIn, signOut } from '../../actions/authActions';

function GoogleAuth() {
  const { signedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(authInit());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const onClick = () => {
    if (signedIn) {
      signOut();
    } else {
      signIn();
    }
  };

  let content;
  if (signedIn === null) {
    return null;
  } else if (signedIn) {
    content = 'Sign Out';
  } else {
    content = 'Sign In';
  }

  return (
    <div className="item">
      <button
        className={classNames('ui google button', {
          green: !signedIn,
          red: signedIn,
        })}
        onClick={onClick}
      >
        <i className="ui icon google" />
        {content}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default GoogleAuth;
```

The code works fine, but it feels like it might be misleading having action calls in JSX but not dispatching it, is it okay?

Comment: While this doesn't keep state in Redux (the example uses Context instead), you may want to look at the API exposed here: https://github.com/asyarb/react-use-googlelogin. It may meet your needs, but if you don't want to add a dependency, simply having a custom hook to expose the functions and logged-in status seems a little cleaner. You could probably create your own hook to wrap it and update the dispatch, but that would probably still use `useEffect` to dispatch the change to Redux (similar to what you already do)

Comment: Okay, thank you!
I had a look into react-use-googlelogin and what they do I already do in my authInit, and then I set up a listener for changes in login with the google API. So if I log out with google I dispatch the change to changeSignedIn. My state in redux gets updated if I log in or out, I left out the reducer, maybe I shouldn't have done that. I might be completely wrong, I have to check into Context more since I don't know much about it. Thank you for the help, think I have to study some more on Context now.

Comment: No worries about the reducer. Really, the two approaches are similar. I guess the only thing I'd recommend is refactoring so you can drop the `useEffect` boilerplate. The inspiration to take from `react-use-googlelogin` is having a single hook to use in your components. You could refactor your current code to create a hook that does the `useEffect` to update the Redux state. That way, in any component that needs the signIn state and the functions can just use that hook...they don't need to also bring in dispatch and do the useEffect.

Comment: Ah okay, now I understand. Ok making that refactor now. Thanks!